# Can't write into focused Textbox while i work with a text-editor

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a problem with focus on a textbox.

I got a global shortcut for my application to set focus on the textbox of the app.

If i use the shortcut i'm doing this:

```
this(Window).Activate()

wantedTextbox.Focus()

Keyboard.Focus(wantedTextbox) // just for testing
```

So it works with e.g. the internet browser, but it won't work with any text-editor. I get focus on the textbox + activate the Window, but if i write, i write into the notepad/VS...

Would be really pleased if somebody got a clue for my issue.

Comment: just tried to reproduce, but for me everything works... But the Keyboard.Focus is important as WPF has Logical and Input Focus!

Comment: Hmmm.. I started the program 2day. And it worked fine too. I don't know why. The only difference is, that i worked with SharpDevelop when i had the problem. Now i reopened the Project in VS2010 and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i solved the problem.
I executed the application with **SharpDevelop** + **C# VS2010Express**.
The SharpDevelop compiled .exe **didn't** work.
The VS2010 one **DID WORK!** I don't know why but that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Once I had faced similar kind of issue in a WPF windows application. Just try to execute the `wantedTextbox.Focus()` command after the window gets loaded. In my case, I had just shifted the code from constructor to the event handeler of `Loaded` event of the window where the TextBox was placed. It worked for me. Just give it a try, it may work for you also.

Comment: it looks like the window is already loaded and just out of focus for me

Comment: try to add `Application.Current.MainWindow.Focus()`, just before `wantedTextbox.Focus()`

Comment: I'm gonna try it. Thanks for helping me!